# IBM Watson Assistant: Dialog working in "Try it out" but not in Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMxLe.png)here is the full souce code.I tried but couldn't able to show the json response in logcat. how can I get the full response from ibm watson & how can I show it in my chatbot.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView conversation;
EditText userInput;
Button btnSend;
JSONObject jsonObject;
Object object;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    conversation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.conversation);
    userInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_input);
    btnSend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);

    final ConversationService myConversationService =
            new ConversationService(
                    "2017-05-26",
                    getString(R.string.username),
                    getString(R.string.password)
            );
 btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final String inputText = userInput.getText().toString();
    conversation.append(
      Html.fromHtml("<p><b>You:</b> " + inputText + "</p>")
    );
    userInput.setText("");
    MessageRequest request = new MessageRequest.Builder()
                            .inputText(inputText)
                            .build();

    myConversationService
    .message(getString(R.string.workspace), request)
    .enqueue(new ServiceCallback<MessageResponse>() {
      @Override
        public void onResponse(MessageResponse response) {
          final String outputText = response.getText().get(0);
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              conversation.append(
                Html.fromHtml("<p><b>Bot:</b> " +outputText + "</p>")
              );
            }
          });
        }

      @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {}
    });
  }
});}}

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:background="#f5d9d9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/user_input_container">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/conversation"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/user_input_container">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:id="@+id/user_input"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="send"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<string name="workspace">a6d8c44e-4ee5-4712-9d7d-d253ba03c2eb</string>
```

In IBM Watson try out virtual device, it is working perfectly.

[image: In IBM Watson Assistant try out virtual device, it is working perfectly]

But in my Android app, it's not displaying. I think, there is something wrong in my Android code, please help.
[edited code image]

Comment: Include details to the dialog. Are the API version the same in the "Try it out" and app? What is the error shown in the "Try it out"?

Comment: I am not sure how you are seeing two responses. Can you provide the JSON response?

Comment: Yes. API version is same.

Comment: How to find JSON response ?? I'm new in app development. Please help me

Comment: Use Log.i above outputText to print the response JSON. You can see the output in Logcat panel on Android Studio. For more info on logging check this link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-application-logging--mobile-4578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example response from Watson Assistant API

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "hello",
      "confidence": 0.9755029201507568
    }
  ],
  "entities": [],
  "input": {
    "text": "Hello"
  },
  "output": {
    "generic": [
      {
        "response_type": "text",
        "text": "Hello! What can I do for you?"
      }
    ],
    "text": [
      "Hello! What can I do for you?"
    ],
    "nodes_visited": [
      "greeting"
    ],
    "log_messages": []
  },
  "context": {
    "conversation_id": "a96ec62f-773c-4e84-8be9-f9dbca9f83d0",
    "system": {
      "dialog_stack": [
        {
          "dialog_node": "root"
        }
      ],
      "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
      "dialog_request_counter": 1,
      "_node_output_map": {
        "greeting": {
          "0": [
            0,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "branch_exited": true,
      "branch_exited_reason": "completed"
    }
  }
}
```

I think the issue is with this line of Android code

```
response.getText().get(0);
```

Once the response is received you are trying to read the first element under getText.get(0). As it can be an array or an object of arrays, you should loop through it to read every value.

Replace

```
final String outputText = response.getText().get(0);
```

with

```
String outputText = "";
                    int length=response.getText().size();
                    Log.i(TAG, "run: "+length);
                    if(length>1) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            outputText += '\n' + response.getText().get(i).trim();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                       outputText = response.getText().get(0);
```

Comment: String outputText = response.getText().get(0); // here is the problem. Right ?? What will be the perfect solution for it ??

Comment: How can i print the rest part ??  Please help. What will be the perfect code for showing full data?

Comment: As mentioned above, can you provide the JSON response I am looking for. As that would help me to see what’s the output and based on that I can propose code here

Comment: I edited my question where i have provided my workspace id and full code.I tried but I couldn't able to find the json response. now can you help me?

Comment: @jannatsuha Its highly recommended not to share the credentials in public forums and also with anyone. Please remove the credentials immediately

Comment: @jannatsuha I edited my answer with the solution code you are looking for.

Comment: @VidyasagarMachuppalli thank u so much. U are trying too much for helping me . There is another problem, in that line ----  int length=response.getOutput().getText().size();   ----- .getText() part is giving me error

Comment: ohh thank u soooo much. It's working perfectly. You have saved my project @VidyasagarMachuppalli